# list index out of range error python when trying to divide elements in a list

Tags: python

I was trying to make a function that returns a new list containing the values the are divisible by parameter `int` but I'm running into the error `list index out of range`. when I research what that meant I found out that I get that error when trying to access int that is out of the lists range but I am not accessing anything out of the listed range. I can't figure out where I went wrong. Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

```
newList=[]
def divisibleMembers(list, int):
    a = list
    for i in a:
        if a[i] % int == 0:
            newList.append(a[i])
            print(newList)
divisibleMembers([1,2,3,4,5], 3)
```

Comment: `i` is the item, not the index. Use `i` instead of `a[i]`. Also don't use built-ins (such as `list` and `int`) as variable or argument names as they will shadow the built-in.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?  A simple `print` in your loop immediately shows you the error.

Comment: @Prune Every programming course/tutorial should start with teaching how to debug your code.

Comment: Yes, it should ... and the  [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) includes a link to this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs), but OP seems to have missed out on these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is not the `index` but the `item`, this is a correction to your code:

```
def divisibleMembers(list, int):
    newList=[]
    for i in list:
        if i % int == 0:
            newList.append(i)
    print(newList)
divisibleMembers([1,2,3,4,5], 3)
```